# Customize layout with Firebase Cloud messaging

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am going to use Firebase cloud messaging in my Android App to send reminder and notifications to users to get them more engaged with my app.

For that reason, I want to have a custom look of the notification. I have gone through the [Cloud Messaging documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) but it only shows how to receive and build a notification when the app is in the foreground. The same does not work if the app is in the background. If the app is in the background then a normal notification is shown.

**I have gone through many posts** stating that I can leave the notification field blank and can put data on the data field but for me, the main problem is that I am not using my custom server to dispatch notification but I am using the Default Notification composer provided by Firebase.

**Is there any way to show custom layout using Default Firebase Notification Composer irrespective of if the app is in the foreground or background?**

Any Help will be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to show custom layout notification using Default FCM panel when the app is in the background.

From [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#backgrounded):

> When your app is in the background, Android directs notification messages to the system tray. A user tap on the notification opens the app launcher by default.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Just one more doubt may be off topic? How can I send a Cloud Notification from Firebase Console which should open at a particular activity rather than my default activity?

Comment: @Rahulrr2602 It is not possible either as far as I know...see the highlighted section of my answer. *notification opens the **app launcher** by default*. A workaround might be, when you pass key-values via firebase console, it creates a notification, but when you click it, the key-value is passed as intent extra(stated in docs) in the launcher activity. When you get your intended extra, you might start your intended activity

Comment: Thanks once again :)