# Firebase + Unity3D = custom Push notification

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to receive custom notifications in a bundle of Unity and Firebase in the same way: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/custom-notification .

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to show a notification like in that link, the Unity equivalent would be the ["Mobile Notifications" package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.mobile.notifications@1.0/manual/index.html). If you have a more specific question about customizing the look and feel, I can try to help. But you should look at the "AndroidNotification" class.

If you intended to link to [how to customize Firebase In-App Messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/customize-messages?platform=android), that API is not yet exposed to Firebase for Unity. You can use [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/unity/client) on Unity, but it doesn't provide the amount of control in that link.

I hope that helps!

--Patrick

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
We want to change the appearance of the notification displayed by the system. Is there such an opportunity in Fairbays out of the box?

Comment: Looking at this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55983794/customize-layout-with-firebase-cloud-messaging , not quite. You can attach images and associate sound (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-image and https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/unity/send-with-console).